# Can anyone please provide me a sample code for jquery animation for a div element inside an infowindow?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-maps

infowindow is of google maps apiv3. any help would be appreciated. i just want a demo code.
i m trying the following code but it is not working. i dont know where is the problem

```
var contentstring = '<div id="box" style="background-color:red; height:100px; width:100px;">' + '</div>' + '<input type="button" id="but">'

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
content: contentstring

});
```

here is the code for jquery animation

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#but").hover(function()
    {
        $("#box").fadeOut();
    },function()
            {
                    $("#box").fadeIn();
            });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your div atrributes are wrong.

`div id=`

***to***

`div class=`